# Sums of inverses of ``odd'' elements  modulo $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory

In a letter to Dirichlet, Gottold Eisenstein stated the congruence:
$$
q(u) \equiv u - \frac{u^2}{2}+ \frac{u^3}{3} - \frac{u^4}{4} + \cdots +  \frac{u^{p-2}}{p-2}-\frac{u^{p-1}}{p-1} \pmod{p}
$$
where $p$ in an odd prime number and 
$$
q(u) = \frac{(1+u)^p -1 - u^p}{p}.
$$
Putting $u=1$  and  using 
$$
1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{p-2}+\frac{1}{p-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}
$$
we get
$$
1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{p-4}+\frac{1}{x} \equiv \frac{q(1)}{2} \pmod{p}
$$
for $x=p-2.$

Question: There is a  $t\quad \quad$ 
 ``odd" solution of the following congruence:
$$
1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{p-4}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{t} \equiv q(1) \pmod{p}
$$
i.e.,

$$
t \in \{p-2,p+2,p+4, \ldots\}.
$$

I just got $-2$ points on this post but I do not see why ?
There not seem to exists negative votes ???

Comment: Of course, such a $t$ exists provided $q(1)+\frac1{p-3}\not \equiv 0 (mod p)$ by the previous identity. Do you want $t$ as a function of $p$?

Comment: @J.C.: thanks for comment. From the comment I detected a technical error in the formula.
Hope new edit is OK and clearer.


Comment: It's still unclear. As far as I remember, the sum of reciprocals of odds $<p$ is treated in my joint paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4337 (one of the lemmas).

Comment: 17 doesn't have a solution.

Comment: @Wadim: Nice, thanks, you think to page 4, formula (21) of your paper ?. There are also very nice formulas
for the fermat quotient , etc in an old paper of Emma Lemmer in Annals of Math 339, 2, 350--360, (1938).


Comment: @Dror: New for me. Interesting then to say something on existence.



Comment: @Luis: Same for 7,11,13,19... Out of the 167 odd primes up to 1000, 60 have a solution.

Comment: @Dror: Some regularity or solutions seems "random" ?


Comment: This would be a good point to advertise sage and its homepage: http://www.sagemath.org/

Comment: I just got $-2$ points in this question, but I do not see why ???
(no negative votes seems to exists here !) 

Comment: @Dror:  Sure !, but for the moment  (old computer in house's office) I only (try to) use gp-pari...
